# Can I use a C# property in javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services

I am very new to webservice programming. Is it possible to set the value of a property in a HttpGet function and later call that property via Javascript/Ajax in a webservice project?

My code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("ScanTicket")]
public IHttpActionResult ScanTicket(string id)
{
    ....
    var totalUsersScanned = scannedList.Count();
    TotalUsersScanned = totalUsersScanned;
```

Property:

```
public int TotalUsersScanned { get; set; }
```

Can I use the value of TotalUsersScanned in my functions.js?

Comment: Woah there, cowboy. I think this question probably merits you reading up a little bit before asking us for help. I'd first read up on Ajax and what "properties" actually mean there. Then I'd check how to expose your methods to Web Services using C#.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to call a webservice which calculates some value (the total users scanned).

Why not just create the webservice? Then when you call it, it calculates the result and returns it to the caller, in this way, you don't have to store it in a property for later retrieval.

If you really want to store it somewhere, you could store it in a session variable and retrieve it later using another call to a webservice.